# Tablespace in cloudsql for mysql

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-sql

I'm new to mysql and GC. It may sound like opinion based question, so sorry for that. But, I really need a right opinion. My company wants to move their on-prem mysql to GC managed mysql. I was looking for feature differences and I found this link: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/features

However, nothing related to tablespaces mentioned here. I wanted to check if we can create tablespaces on GC for mysql and what other things can be missing there.

If anyone has exact idea about pros and cons of GC managed mysql..that will be really helpful.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Google Cloud SQL is a managed service which means storage is also managed. Specifying storage locations is not supported. Why do you need this feature?

Comment: @JohnHanley - I know google managed database will auto-scale. But, I don't know in case of partitioned table - how does it do partition allocation physically. On on-prem - what we used to do that we keep each partition to separate disk. Likewise, we get a good performance.

Comment: You do not control those features. Google Cloud SQL is a "managed" service.

Comment: @JohnHanley - if you have used google managed databases in past ..would you recommand that?

Comment: You will have to do your own research to determine if Cloud SQL is for you. It is an excellent product that I have been using for years (since it was first released). Remember that you do not have "privileged" rights as Google Cloud manages the database system.

Comment: You could just hire a VM and install what you want on it? Adv. **total** control + **latest** software versions - AWS/GCE/whatever are frequently (quite a way) behind the upstream db provider!

Comment: @Vérace - that is good advice for database administrators with good budgets. HA, failover, read replicas, backups, snapshots, etc. are usually beyond the casual cloud user's budget and skillset to deploy, manage and update/patch.

Comment: good opinion from both of you. Do we have any clue about performance / normal query performance comparison from both?

Comment: Now you are moving into the area of opinions. Matters regarding performance require clearly specifying the "what" to determine the results. You will need to benchmark your particular application/usage. One nice feature of managed databases is the easy/fast ability to scale up and down to match performance requirements.